# ExtJS - Post date values as Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, extjs, unix-timestamp

I use an `editorgrid` to edit elements from a `JsonStore`. The `JsonStore` uses a `HttpProxy` to update the backend database.

My problem is that the backend API expects `fromTs` and `toTs` to be Unix timestamps, but when a record is updated, the resulting http post contains a date formatted like this: `Wed Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2010`

I've searched the API documentation for a parameter to control the post format, but I've not been able to find anything. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
 myJsonStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSave: true,
  proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
   api: {
    create: '/create/',
    read: '/read/',
    update: '/update/',
    destroy:'/destroy/'
   }
  }),
  writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
   encode: true,
   writeAllFields: true
  }),
  idProperty: 'id',
  fields: [
   {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
   {name: 'fromTs', type: 'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'},
   {name: 'toTs',  type: 'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'}
  ]
 });
```

The `editorgrid` is configured like this:

```
 {
  xtype: 'editorgrid',
  clicksToEdit: 1,
  columns: [
         {header: "Id", dataIndex: 'id', editable: false},
   {header: "From", dataIndex: 'fromTs', editor: new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'd.m.Y', startDay: 1}), xtype: 'datecolumn', format: 'd.m.Y'},     
   {header: "To", dataIndex: 'toTs', editor: new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'd.m.Y', startDay: 1}), xtype: 'datecolumn', format: 'd.m.Y'}
  ],
  store: myJsonStore
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this case is old, but I found a solution to this problem that I never came around to post here.

I added a listener to the proxy's beforewrite event, and manipulated the post params there

```
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    api: {
        create: '/create/',
        read:   '/read/',
        update: '/update/',
        destroy:'/destroy/'
    },
    listeners: {
        beforewrite: function(proxy, action, record, params) {
            var fromTs = record.data.fromTs;
            var toTs = record.data.toTs;

            if(record.data.fromTs) record.data.fromTs = fromTs.format('U');
            if(record.data.toTs) record.data.toTs = toTs.format('U');

            // Update record to be sent
            // root = store.reader.root
            params.root = Ext.util.JSON.encode(record.data);

            // Restore record
            record.data.fromTs = fromTs;
            record.data.toTs = toTs;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hook into the `validateedit` event or `afteredit` event of your `EditorGridPanel` and convert the user-entered-value back into a timestamp using a Date parsing method.  I'm guessing that `EditorGridPanel` is updating the records in the store verbatim without converting them back into timestamps, so you have to do that manually.  So I'm thinking maybe something like:

```
grid.on('validateedit', function(event) {
  if (isDateColumn(column)) {
    event.record.data[event.field] = dateToTimestamp(event.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It seems like date fields uses this date format for internal storage regardless of format parameters. When I set the value to a timestamp, the date field will resolve this as an invalid date. The json post will still contain the unwanted date format. `{"id":"6","fromTs":"2010-10-12T00:00:00","toTs":"NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN"}`

Comment: Your only option in that case might be then to override some of the behavior in `doResponse()` and create the POST with your own parameters, formatted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JsonWriter does not respect the dateFormat field used in your JsonReader.  This post describes the issue along with some code that will address it.  You can find it [here](http://www.prodromus.com/2011/04/15/extjs-jsonwriter-not-respecting-dateformat-used-with-jsonreader).